# Not getting exceptions raised with namespace from servicestack filter

Tags: c#, servicestack

I implemented a couple of filters a few months back and I set

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://schemas.servicestack.net/types",  ClrNamespace = "My.NameSpace")]
```

in my assembly and made sure all by DTOS are under the correct namespace "My.NameSpace".

If I raise an exception in my Service (using RestServiceBase) my exception is serialized correctly with the namespace set to "http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" in the error response DTO.

If I raise an exception in the filter, then the namespace "http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" is set in the error response DTO as above. All this is fine and worked.

However, for some reason today when an exception is raised in a filter the namespace is blank in the error response DTO. I am also getting the StackTrace element in the error response DTO set with my exception stack trace (it was blank when all was working).

Since my client checks for the namespace "http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" all my error handling from exceptions in filters are not being shown correctly on the client.

Any ideas where I should check?

Comment: Maybe settings issue - SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { DebugMode = true }); From documentation: By default display StackTraces in your Response DTOs are disabled, but they're a good to have for development, which you can enable with above.

Comment: Currently DebugMode is false and I still get the <StackTrace> element. It is the namespace being blank that is causing me the issue.

Comment: Also if I set debugmode to true, the stack trace I get gives me information on dto, etc where as when set to false it gives me my code stack trace. Once again it the namespace I am missing in the service filters.